# CI pipeline fails even though it is doing what its supposed to

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

Let me start by saying I just started Azure and by no means a pro and been following guides here and there. So, I'm following [this](https://www.4bes.nl/2019/06/16/deploy-azure-functions-for-powershell-with-azure-devops/?unapproved=2580&moderation-hash=6e499ac6325d23da0db71f5f541086f3#comment-2580) article by deploying [this](https://github.com/Ba4bes/AzFA-GetRunningVMs) repo in my own Azure DevOps subscription, after I changed the resource group, subscription, and function name, I build and run the CI pipeline, then at the "Deploy Azure Resources" I'd get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW6Cw.jpg) error even though after the pipeline exits, the resources are created the way its supposed to, I also notice if I re run the same pipeline the 2nd time, it works perfectly which is confusing. Here is the modified the YAML template that I have

```
name: DeployAzureFunction
variables:
  FunctionAppName: 'test'
  AzureConnection: 'DevOps-Test'
  ResourcegGroupName: 'test'

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'  # must quote since "*" is a YAML reserved character; we want a string



stages:

- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Test_FA
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-2019
    steps:
    - task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
      displayName: 'Test ARM Deployment'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(AzureConnection)
        resourceGroupName: $(ResourcegGroupName)
        location: 'East US 2'
        csmFile: Deployment/azuredeploy.json
        deploymentMode: Validation
    - powershell: |
       Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force -Scope CurrentUser
       Install-Module -Name Pester -Force -Scope CurrentUser -SkipPublisherCheck
       Install-Module -Name PSScriptAnalyzer -Force -Scope CurrentUser
      displayName: 'Install Pester and import module'
   
  - job: Build_FA
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-2019
    steps:
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive FunctionApp'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: FunctionApp
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/zip/FunctionApp.zip'
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
      inputs:
        artifactName: 'zip'
        targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/zip'

- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - job: Deploy_ARM
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-2019
    steps:
    - task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
      displayName: 'Deploy Azure Resources'
      continueOnError: true
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(AzureConnection)
        resourceGroupName: $(ResourcegGroupName)
        location: 'East US 2'
        csmFile: Deployment/azuredeploy.json
        csmParametersFile: Deployment/azuredeploy.parameters.json
        overrideParameters: '-functionAppName $(FunctionAppName)'
        deploymentMode: Incremental
        deploymentOutputs: DeploymentOutput
```

And this is the unmodified azuredeploy.json that I think is causing the issue but not sure why

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "functionAppName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify the name of the function application"
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify the location for the function application resources"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "hostingPlanName": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
        "storageacccount": "[toLower(parameters('functionAppName'))]",
        "storageAccountName": "[concat('storage', variables('storageacccount'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "kind": "Storage",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "name": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Y1",
                "tier": "Dynamic",
                "size": "Y1",
                "family": "Y",
                "capacity": 0
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "kind": "functionapp",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
                "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', parameters('functionAppName'))]"
            ],
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "properties": {
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                            "value": "powershell"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2017-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                            "value": "~2"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
                            "value": "[reference(resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', parameters('functionAppName')), '2018-05-01-preview').InstrumentationKey]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')),'2017-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
                            "value": "[toLower(parameters('functionAppName'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "name": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
                "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('hostingPlanName'))]"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
            "name": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
            "kind": "Web",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": {
                "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('functionAppName')))]": "Resource"
            },
            "properties": {
                "ApplicationId": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
                "Application_Type": "web"
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "principalId": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[reference(concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('functionAppName')), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId]"
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me figure out why I get that error in the first run, I'd appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Resources are created yet the Deployment operation fails because there is a problem in caclulating the output variable.

Most likely it is because of the way you are trying to access the Service Principal Id of the App Service. The '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default' part.

You probably want something like this:

```
[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('functionAppName')), '2016-08-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]
```